# Continue Processing Job After User Exits

Tags: c#

I am developing a MVC application that has a long running job that processes customer accounts. I would like this process to be able to fire and forget, meaning the user can click "Start" and then exit the application. This job would continue to process accounts and keep track of its progress (within the application or log file or database updates). The user can then log back in and see the progress at any point.

I have been attempting to research this and [BackgroundWorker](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETBackgroundWorker-5a0cea51) seems to be what I want to do but I am unsure if it will continue once the user ends the sessions (logs off).

Will BackgroundWorker continue to process the request after the user logs off or will the process end once the user ends the session?

Comment: Create a separate executable and run it as a service, use the UI to kick off the service. BackgroundWorker will exit when the application closes.

Comment: Hmm what about something like [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/)?

Comment: Looks interesting but has additional dependencies that you may not be able to satisfy. If you have the ability to meet the prerequisites for it, go for it, otherwise a simple service isn't that hard to set up and control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I's suggest to use [`ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx).

If you want to be able to resume, you should use some solution such as [HangFire](http://hangfire.io/)

Comment: MVC is killed just when IIS kills Application Pool. Not when user logs out.

Comment: @CzechDeveloper is there a way to run a thread within MVC independent of the user then?

Comment: Any thread separate from "main" thread is independent from user.

Comment: This HangFire thing was great I don't know how did I miss it for so many time! Thank you.